# How to find optimum value to set in setValidateAfterInactivity for my app

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

For default 2 seconds, I am getting socket Exception. How do I ensure the value set is neither too high nor too low to cause performance issues.

Any tools or techniques to find

Comment: why is it voted down?

Comment: the sites I have visited say to run a thread which closes expired connection per 5 seconds or 1 second. But when default value is 2 secs, how can a parallel thread closing connections in 5 seconds will help. my question is how do I find what value I should set? What are the tools and techniques to determine same? It seem people are more interested in down voting than actually helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using myConnectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();

before myHttpClient.execute(myTarget, getReq);

along with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

I did not require to setValidateAfterInactivity then.

This worked for me.

Comment: That certainly works, but calls to `#closeExpiredConnections` are not cheap and there is always a chance of a race. Some connections may expire between `#closeExpiredConnections`  call and next request execution

Comment: Suit yourself by any means

Answer (score 1):

Just set this value to something like 200 ms and be done with it. This will ensure that series of related requests will get executed without a performance penalty of stale connection check, but connections idle longer than 200 ms will get checked.